# The Basic Practice of Statistics vs. Introduction to the Practice of Statistics

Tags: textbooks, statistics

How does [David S. Moore; William I. Notz; Michael Fligner's 2021 9 edn. *The Basic Practice of Statistics*](https://www.macmillanlearning.com/college/us/product/The-Basic-Practice-of-Statistics/p/1319244378) differ from [David S. Moore; George P. McCabe; Bruce Craig's 2021 10 edn *Introduction to the Practice of Statistics*](https://www.macmillanlearning.com/college/us/product/Introduction-to-the-Practice-of-Statistics/p/1319244440)? Publisher's the same. Please don't discuss or recommend other books in this thread.  Out of these two, I prefer a book that

1. uses color, esp. for diagrams and pictures.
2. offers a free, accessible solutions manual to all exercises in the book.

David S. Moore is credited as the first author, but he's [Long retired. Please be aware that all of my texts are now other hands, even though they continue to bear my name. Please direct text questions to the current authors.](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/%7Edsmoore/)

Answer (score 1):

Basic Practice is a lower level book than Intro Practice.

I used Basic Practice for a no-prerequisite data analysis course, and I used Intro Practice for an algebra-prerequisite elementary stats course.

Both are in color and have free instructor manuals that students can easily find on the internet.

Comment: I couldn't find instructor solution manual ("ISM") for the aforementioned editions of either of these two books. I'm not referring to older editions.